# A is an n by n matrix such that $A^3=2I$.

Tags: linear-algebra

A is an n by n matrix such that $A^3 = 2I$.
(1) Is $A$ invertible? If it is, then what is $A^{-1}$?
(2) Is $A+I$ invertible? If it is, then what is $(I+A)^{-1}$

The original version of the question is not in English, so maybe there are some grammar mistakes, sorry in advance.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I have been having no ideas for 2 hours

Comment: Okay. Let’s start by asking: when is a matrix said to be invertible ? What are the criteria for invertibility?

Comment: You mean 1/3√2 ? Actually I haven't learnt much about linear algebra, I only know matrices in linear algebra.

Comment: em, invertibility means there is an A¯ ¹ such that AA¯ ¹=I ?

Comment: Suppose $Ax = 0$ then what would that imply about $A^3 x$?

Comment: So that is 1/3√2 +1？

Comment: So is that A3x=A2?

Comment: You know the minimal polynomial of $A$ must divide $x^3-2 $.

Comment: I haven't learnt about polynomial matrix yet......I know its concept but I don't know its application.

Comment: Are you aware of the spectral theorem then?

Comment: Nope......even never heard about it.

Comment: What does $A^3=2I$ say about the eigenvalues of $A$?

Comment: Forget that. Note that $A ( {1 \over 2} A^2) = I$. What does that tell you about $A^{-1}$?

Comment: That is, A-1=1/2A2?

Comment: You need to learn mathjax.

Comment: I already realize that...that will take some time.

Comment: Yes. $A^{-1}=\frac12A^2$. But how do you know that the inverse exists?

Comment: @insipidintegrator Any matrix that satisfies $AB=BA = I$ is an inverse.

Comment: Uh.., I was asking the OP. @copper.hat

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think we are beyond that part?

Comment: Well, I tried, but it seems I need more time to learn how to use mathjax. Maybe you could  show me all the  steps? I would try to figure them out.

Comment: If $x^3=2$ then what is $x^3+1$? Other than $(x+1)(x^2-x+1)$, that is :-)

Answer (score 1):

$A$ quite obviously has $Nullity(A)=\emptyset$ and so is invertible. You can argue by contradiction supposing that if it had a nullspace, there exists an $x\neq 0$ such that $Ax=0 \Rightarrow A^3x=0\neq 2x=2Ix=A^3x$. One way to find the inverse, a little different (kinda worse tbh) than the one in the comments is to denote the inverse by $A^{-1}$ which we know exists from above, and go from there. We have $I=(A^{-1})^3A^3=(A^{-1})^32I=2(A^{-1})^3$. Thus we have $I=2(A^{-1})^3 \Rightarrow IA^2=2(A^{-1})^3A^2 \Rightarrow A^2=2A^{-1}\Rightarrow \frac{1}{2}A^2=A^{-1}$. We also have $A+I$ is invertible, which we can argue by showing that $0$ is not an eigenvalue. By contradiction if $0$ was an eigenvalue then we have $\exists x\neq0;(A+I)x=0x \Rightarrow Ax=-Ix \Rightarrow Ax=-x$. So $-1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. But then we have $A^3x=(-1)^3x=-x$ but also $A^3x=2Ix=2x$ and $-x=2x$ is a contradiction since this implies that $x$ is the zero vector, which it is not by assumption. If you want to try to form a contradiction yourself, another way is to take $(A+I)x=0$, and multiply it by $A^{-1}$ and use what we know for the eigenvalue of A. If this is not enough another hint is to think of the eigenvalue of $A^{-1}$ for the vector $x$. I think this works but I only thought about it in my head sorry.

Answer (score 0):

A matrix $B$ that satisfies $AB=BA = I$ is an inverse of $A$.

Since $A ({1 \over 2} A^2) = I$ we see that $A^{-1} = {1 \over 2} A^2$.

Suppose $x^3 = 2$, then we see that
${1 \over x+1} = {1 \over x} (1-{1 \over x} + {1 \over x^2} - {1 \over x^3} + {1 \over x^4} - {1 \over x^5} +\cdots) $, and using $x^3 = 2$ we get
$=1+(-1+{1 \over x} - {1 \over x^2}) (1-{1 \over 2} + {1 \over 2^2} - \cdots)$ and using ${x^3 \over 2} =1$ we get
$= {1 \over 3} (1-x+x^2)$.
(Check by multiplying by $1+x$.)

This suggests trying $B={1 \over 3} (I-A+A^2)$ as an inverse for $I+A$.

As above, if we multiply $(I+A)B$ we get $I$ hence
$(I+A)^{-1} = {1 \over 3} (I-A+A^2)$.

**Addendum**: Another approach to computing $(A+I)^{-1}$.

We want to find a polynomial $p$ such that $(x+1) p(x)$ is a non zero constant. Since $x^3=2$ we posit that a degree two polynomial will suffice. Hence we are looking for $a,b$ such that $(x+1) (1 + ax+bx^2)$ is a constant.
Expanding (and using $x^3=2$) gives
$a=-1, b=1$ which is the same as above.

Comment: can u pls explain more?

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: how u got $\frac{1}{x+1}$, the other equality, and $\frac{x^2}{2}=1$

Comment: ${1 \over 1+x}$ is the analogue of $(I+A)^{-1}$. And we know that $A^3 = 2I$.

Comment: @Goob See Jyrki's comment above for a much better explanation.

Comment: Ah I see, this is very clever. I have never seen finding inverses with this kind of thinking before!

Comment: @Goob I added a more straightforward approach triggered by Jyrki's comment.